# How to sum up a 2D array elements together?

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple code sample of what I'm after:

```js
var length = 5;
var arrays = [];


// our arrays

         slice1  
         ↓  slice2
            ↓  ↓ slice3
var a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
var b =    [2, 2, 2, 2];
var c =       [3, 3, 3];
var d =          [4, 4];
var e =             [5];
                     ↑ slice5
// put all above arrays into one array
arrays = arrays.concat([a]);
arrays = arrays.concat([b]);
arrays = arrays.concat([c]);
arrays = arrays.concat([d]);
arrays = arrays.concat([e]);
console.log(arrays)

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
 /*         
I want a code here which does this:
var slice = [];
slice[0] = arrays[0][0] => 1
slice[1] = arrays[0][1] + arrays[1][0] => 1 + 2
slice[2] = arrays[0][2] + arrays[1][1] + arrays[2][0] => 1 + 2 + 3
...
*/
}
```

Actually, I want to assign slice variables based on a 2D array elements. But how?

Note: I can log the `arrays` but the problem is to calculate each slice in the `for` loop because I may have different `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` or different `length`.

Comment: do you have a result?

Comment: The error's start at assigning an array of arrays in the first arr.concat

Comment: Added a note to the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best approach to an algorithm as you've described is to find an inductive rule, just like you aimed to!

```js
var length = 5;
var arrays = [];
var slices = new Array(length).fill(0);

// I thought this was a more elegant way of initializing
for (let i = length; i > 0; i--){
  arrays[length-i] = new Array(i).fill(length+1-i);
}

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    slices[i] += arrays[j][i - j];
  }
}
console.log(slices);
```

Comment: but what if we want different lengths?

Comment: This seems to depend on the arrays being sorted by length (which might be okay since they are in the OP).

Comment: @SaraRee What do you mean by different lengths? It depends if the "inductive" rule still applies ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array and take an offset for the index by iterating from the end for the inner array. This works for an arbitrary length of the arrays.

Some different values to proof the calculation.

```
[[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000],
    [20, 200, 2000, 20000],
        [300, 3000, 30000],
             [4000, 40000],
                   [50000]]

[ 1, 30, 600,10000, 150000]
```

```js
var array = [[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000], [20, 200, 2000, 20000], [300, 3000, 30000], [4000, 40000], [50000]],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => a.reduceRight((q, v, i, { length }) => {
        if (q.length < length - i) q.unshift(v);
        else q[q.length - length + i]+= v;
        return q;
    }, r), []);
    
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this for any arrangement of arrays. It should work even if the arrays are in different orders to different lengths. The trick is assigning zero if the array isn't initialized at the particular index.

```js
var a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
var b =    [2, 2, 2, 2];
var c =       [3, 3, 3];
var d =          [4, 4];
var e =             [5];
// put all above arrays into one array
let arrays = [a, b, c, d, e]

let sums = arrays.reduce((sums, arr) => {
    arr.reverse().forEach((n, i) => sums[i] = (sums[i] || 0) + n)
    return sums
}, []).reverse()

console.log(sums)
```

Other arrangements/lengths will work as expected:

```js
var a =   [10, 2, 2, 2];
var b =[1, 20, 1, 1, 1];
var c =       [3, 3, 3];
var d =          [4, 4];
var e =       [5, 5, 5];

let arrays = [a, b, c, d, e] 

let sums = arrays.reduce((sums, arr) => {
    arr.reverse().forEach((n, i) => sums[i] = (sums[i] || 0) + n)
    return sums
}, []).reverse()

console.log(sums)
```

Comment: It works incorrectly. You're adding zeros to the tail of array, but should be adding them to the head. To fix this you should reverse each array first: `arr.reverse().forEach(...)`

Comment: _Now_ it shows the correct result, but that's just for this convenient data set. Try to change first `2` to `20` in the first array and you'll see the issue.

Comment: Ah, yes! The power of a better test case. Edited, thanks @Styx.